# How do I set presentation attributes of Image tags that can be found within SVGs (Files or Inline)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, snap.svg

I am writing an SVG editor program. I am trying to implement highlighted feel for when an element (`<image>`, not `<img>`) is clicked. I have implemented this for other elements like `<circle>`, by setting `stroke`, `stroke-width`, and `stroke-dash-array`. But setting the presentation attributes of the `<image>` tag, either by setting the attributes directly or through CSS styling, is not taking effect. I also tried the border style but it's not working. How can I achieve this?

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image#attributes) , `<image>` is meant to have have global attributes, including presentation, which ultimately means this should work. If you also inspect `<image>` with a browser you will see it will highlight like it follows box model.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1370 1170" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <image width="128" height="128" x="617.9207153320312" href="data:some-valid-link" style="stroke-width: 3px; stroke-dasharray: 7px;" stroke="#3aa2c2"></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: Are you saying that the `image` element itself refers an SVG image with your `href="data:some-valid-link"` there? Then I don't think you can apply styling "from the outside" like that, in this scenario the same limitations should apply, as if you embedded the SVG image you want to format with `<img src="...">` in HTML directly.

Comment: The href can refer to a dataUrl of raster (png, jpeg, etc) and svg itself. I am also using `<image> </image>` instead of  `<img> </img>` because the later don't work inside inline svg., so in this case I am trying to set the presentation attribute of the `<image> </image>` .

Comment: @dareedyone if you want the data URL to be different, edit it and change it. You can't change the values from the image element's style attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can set stroke on an image.

Usually those attributes are used to 'draw' vector image. Here you're trying to put a stroke on a raster image.

If you want to put lines around a square image you could use a *border* to achieve it.

If you want to put lines around a complicated shape, I don't think it's possible to do that in CSS. You would need to add that in graphics software.

Comment: Like I mentioned in other comments. I am writing an svg editor program. I have found that Svgs will/can contain raster images and svgs itself with `<image></image>` and `<img></img>` don't work. According to [Mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image) `<image>` are meant to have global attributes which include presentation i.e strokes and the likes so I don't know why this is not working. I can't also set the border with css as an alternative. If you inspect image element with chrome you will see it is highlighted and still follows a box model.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restyle an external SVG, if you load it in an `<img>` tag.

Instead, you could paste the `<svg>` code directly into your HTML, and apply styles like this ([source svg](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_polygon3)):

```css
svg {
  width: 500px;
}

svg path,
svg polygon {
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-dasharray: 10px;
}
```

```html
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

Comment: I am writing an svg editor program. I have found that Svgs will/can contain raster images and svgs itself with `<image></image>` and `<img></img>` don't work. According to [Mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image) `<image>` are meant to have global attributes which include presentation i.e strokes and the likes so I don't know why this is not working. I can't also set the border with css as an alternative. If you inspect `image` element with chrome you will see it is highlighted and still follows a box model.

Answer (score -1):

You would need and SVG with a more specific code targeting all the vectors and not just a  tag. Then you could make groups of the parts of the image/draw you want to style. You can do this by using illustrator, then after grouping the parts, your code will have a 'g' tag: `<g id="group_to_style" >` with an ID that you have named when doing the groups. Then using CSS you can target the groups of the SVG and style or even animate. Like gru said, with an  you cant style or animate anything.